# VBA Macro for copying and pasting columns on same excel sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to know how to copy the 3rd row to the 100th row for the 2nd column into the 3rd column how would this be done?

Comment: Have you tried google, recording a macro, I think you could of got the answer in the time taken to add the question.

Answer (score 0):

Insert this line to your code

```
Range("B3:B100").Copy Destination:=Range("C3:C100")
```

The range destination can be changed depending on which range you want to paste the data.